# How to set a script for an asset using Waves IDE?

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, wavesplatform, ride

How to set a script for an asset manually using the IDE. Does this imply that you first create the asset and then convert it? Is there a restriction on who can set a script for an asset? such as only the creating wallet can set a script (such as with  issue new tokens), or can ANYONE set a script for an asset that is inside their wallet.  Is it possible to set a script that affects tokens not in your own wallet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assets that were issued without a script cannot become scripted. You can create an asset that behaves as non-scripted but can be upgraded later, by issuing an asset with a script: 'true'.

A smart asset's script can be changed via SetAssetScriptTransaction. Only the issuer can change the asset's script.